# Python Dictionaries key pairings

Tags: python, dictionary

I've checked around and can't seem to find what exactly I am looking for. I've tried to do this a few different ways, but the best way I can come up with is using an empty dictionary and adding some key pairings. I'm unsure what exactly `random.choice(list(weapons.values()))`  is pulling from the dictionary. Is it getting the key or the value?

```
import random 

weapons = {}
weapons[3] = "Rock"
weapons[2] = "Scissors"
weapons[1] = "Paper"

player_1 = input("Choose your weapon. ")

player_2 = random.choice(list(weapons.values()))

if player_1 == "Rock" and player_2 == "Paper":
    print(player_2,"Computer wins!")

elif player_2 == "Rock" and player_1 == "Paper":
    print(player_2,"Player 1 wins!")

elif player_1 > player_2:
    print(player_2,"Player 1 wins!")

elif player_2 > player_1:
    print(player_2,"Computer wins!")

elif player_1 == player_2:
    print(player_2,"Tie!")  

else:
    print("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors. ")
```

Comment: It is suggestive that `.values()` will give you `values` not `keys`

Comment: instead of using `dict` i.e. `{}` you can use `list` i.e. `weapons = []` and use `append` mehtod. The use of dictionary seems unnecessary here

Comment: I'll try that. I went with a dictionary so that I could give the strings some "weight" for lack of a better term. I was unsure how to make the 'Rock' heavier than the 'Scissor' with a list.

Comment: But you are not using the weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.values always return values of dictionary keys. Please check this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/values

random.choice is selecting random values at a time from the list of dictionary values .

Comment: Thank you! Seems I just needed to change .values to .keys and change the input to be an int.